# Acumatica Bill Of Materials - Archive by API

Tags: acumatica

By API (18.200.001 or 20.200.001), I am trying to archive a BillOfMaterials record that is active.

Let's say I have BOMID "Abc123" Revision "A" and I just added BOMID "Abc123" Revision "B". What I want to do is set revision A as Archived.

I have tried setting revision A to hold and that does not even work.

```
{
  "BOMID": {"value": "Abc123"},
  "Revision": {"value": "A"},
  "Hold": {"value": True}
}
```

I have tried setting the "Status" value to "Archived". I have tried setting the "Active" value too False. They all report an internal error with an unhelpful stack trace.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the "Action" on the BOM entity called  "Archive BOM".   This will mimic what happens on the screen.  You may need to extend the MANUFACTURING endpoint to add this action to it because it does exist by default (at least not in the 18.100.001 version)